# How to create waves in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to create waves like used in the following site:

https://www.payumoney.com/

How do I do this?

Comment: Hi Shashank, welcome to SE:GD.  You should really read the [help] and take the [tour] - this will help you understand how the site works, and how to ask a question.  Could you show us what you have tried already, please?

Comment: After looking at that site, the background is a file called '../../images/landingpages/wave.svg'. The file format is [SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). You can use editors such as InkScape to create this type of image.

Comment: `Pen tool` to make the basic wave shape, then `Layer Style: Gradient Overlay` to add the gradient. If you make the gradient translucent, the layer `Fill` should be set to `0%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an svg - that is, it's purely ***vector*** art. It's important you understand the difference between ***vector*** and ***raster*** images and art, but I'm not going to bore you or waste your time with a lengthy explanation when there are a slew of questions / answers on that topic here in **GDSE**: suffice it to say vector is lines and fills with infinitely sharp edges and no pixels, where raster is all pixels.

[Raster, Vector, what are they?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2873/raster-vector-what-are-they)

[What are the differences between vector graphics and raster graphics?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-graphics-and-raster-graphics)

You *absolutely can* create vector art in Photoshop using the pen tool, and once you've drawn a sine wave shape, use a gradient fill on the layer with proper transparency settings - the point here is that as the image you linked to was vector, our answers will be tuned to getting you vector output, not pixel paint - so for example, although you could also use the shape you draw to make a selection and manually fill it with the gradient fill tool, that would drive this to being a pixel-painting exercise and you'd not get a sheer vector SVG back out (I examined your specific website's background wave.svg and it's pure vector for sure - no pixels) so stay with the layer gradient overlay approach, and export out an svg file.

I ***can*** tell you that *most* of us here in **GDSE** would *prefer* to do this task in a vector app, such as Adobe Illustrator, Affinity Designer, Inkscape, Xara, Sketch... as the tools in these apps are specifically set up for vector art work, and so it would be both faster and easier in one of those tools than in Photoshop - if you have one of these available, I'd say try that. If not, as previously said: Photoshop, pen tool> layer gradient overlay > export svg.