# What size and file type for vectorising?

Tags: vector

Hi I have created a word file with my company name in my chosen font and colour
I now want to use this again and again on my websites etc
what size and file type should I put this in to have it vectorised? many thanks I would be very grateful for any help

Comment: If it's just a font... all you need do is name the font and the color and then reset it in a vector application (or practically any application). You can save your Word file as a PDF and the type will be vector.

Comment: Hi Wag, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3):

I'd encourage you to hire a professional because honestly based on your question you don't have the skillset to do what you're after. Vectors for example lack size by definition, websites also don't typically use a vector logo though they could these days with SVG, but not common. Scott told you how to make a vector, but that's only applicable for print usage. Since you seem to not fully understand the differences between raster and vector you should probably hire or at least consult with a professional. This question might also be useful to you:

[What are the differences between vector graphics and raster graphics?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-graphics-and-raster-graphics)

I already addressed size which is irrelevant in vector. For type it would be .PDF, .EPS, .SVG or one of the Proprietary formats such as .AI or .AFDESIGN. As Scott mentioned in Comments you could just export a PDF from your Word Processor and it would be a vector format.

Comment: I must say that i dont particularily like the accepted answer of the linked question. I mean a raster image is a matrix and that too is mathematical. Anyway your answer is spot on in anycse.