# Illustrator: how to draw smooth lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-quality, line-art

I am creating logos or illustrations which display as pixelated lines. I am using the pen tool, any settings i should change or any tool i should add?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can not see any lines that are distorted. But yes you prbably need to disable snap to pixel. Nothing good comes out of enabling that feature.

Comment: You might want to turn *off* **Pixel Preview** in the View menu. Especially if the artwork is designed for print reproduction. Unfortunately if the artwork is to be displayed digitally, there is *no way* to remove indicators of pixels since everything *requires* pixels to display.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about the pixelation...

You have pixel preview enabled, which shows your work as it would look rasterized at 72 PPI. Disable it from the View menu *(View → Pixel Preview)* or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

As for JPG; that is a raster format (i.e. made of pixels) so you will obviously see the same. To keep your lines infiinitely crisp, you need to save to a vector format.

See [What are the differences between vector graphics and raster graphics?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/260/52050)

Comment: Also... you should back up your computer