# Do pdfs scale for printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, pdf

I have a large vector image I've drawn in adobe illustrator that at some point needs to be printed on a separate machine without access to illustrator. If I shrink the image to decrease file size for upload then export the image as a PDF can it be scaled at the receiving end again via printer settings and still maintain quality if enlarged?

Comment: Shrinking a purely vector image will not reduce the file size.

Comment: Fair enough but whatabout the print quality?

Comment: Vectors are infinitely rescalable - they have no pixels.

Comment: Perhaps time to go find out what the difference between raster and vector is.  This website should help: https://www.psprint.com/resources/difference-between-raster-vector/ - I have no affiliation with this website/company.

Comment: In fact, there's already a good question with answers here on GD.SE https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-graphics-and-raster-graphics

Comment: So I'm aware of the differences between raster and vector and know that I can keep scaling a vector without loss of quality but I just wasn't sure on the print aspect. e.g if I upload an exported vector as a PDF for download, could anyone else increase the size to whatever they wanted via their print options without having access to vector software and again without loss of quality. It appears PDFs though can themselves be vector or raster so I think I might need to look at the export settings

Comment: OK, I added an answer.

Comment: @TommyBs It does not really sound like you are though. In fact most people who claim so don't really understand the nuance. I mean lots of people can recite vector drawings are infinitely scale able because thay are mathematical entities and all that. Not realizing that they in fact are NOT infinitely scale able, and that a raster image is just mathematics too. And why only certain kinds of mathematics survive trough the PDF pipe, and how vector images are in fact giving away you artwork as is. See the tools in illustrator are limited by what PDF supports and not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator exports vectors inside a PDF as vector, unless you rasterized them first. Vector files are infinitely rescalable, either in print, or when viewing on screen with suitable image viewing software.

Shrinking a vector image's physical size will not reduce the file size of the image.

If there was a printer big enough, you could print a vector image the size of the Empire State Building, and it would still look tack sharp. Vectors do not contain pixels, therefore there is no degradation when making them larger.

Comment: HOWEVER! dont forget, things such as Stroke and effects like Drop Shadows are affected by scaling, as they don't scale with the vector.

Comment: Good way to check: open the pdf in acrobat, preview or whatever and keep zooming in. Are the lines still sharp? Then you're probably good to go.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft I'm talking about plain common old vectors, not raster effects applied to a vector.  Yes you are right however, that these could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

A vector AI file saved to PDF is pretty much the same. Everything remains in vector shapes, which means you can scale it up or down without losing any quality.

Resolution and image quality is only a concern if working with raster formats (PSD, TIF, JPG, PNG, etc).