# Online Solution for editing (breaking apart) Vector files

Tags: vector, designers, image-editing

outside of Adobe and Corel Draw is there an online solution for taking a PNG, JPG or SVG file and breaking it apart to change the colors or styles?

Comment: PNG and JPG are raster, not vector.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I should note that PNG and JPG are Raster, not Vector. See "[What are the differences between vector graphics and raster graphics?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/260/63979)"

As for a vector editing program:

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) is a free before editing software. Available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

There are also many online solutions, which a simple search for "Online vector editor" will bring up lots of results.

Answer (score 0):

First  break the raster file (Jpeg, png bmp) to vector using "Vector Magic" software (search online for free software). Then save it as vector (.ai, .cdr, .eps .svg). Adjust the tracing methods you want. Next you open in your preferred vector software and adjust the points and colors.