# Can we use Photoshop for the print related designs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I know it is better to use Illustrator but still, I want to know.
As far as I know, we can use photoshop for Digital printing. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Amit, welcome to GDSE. I'm not sure I fully understand your question, since you can print any design you made using any software.  Photoshop is a raster image editor, and is very different from Illustrator which is a vector image editor.  Are you confused about the difference?  If so, there [are answers here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-graphics-and-raster-graphics) which might help you.

Comment: You can use anything you want, as long as it works for you. Many graphic designers use Illustrator, Indesign, and Photoshop all in a single workflow because they all do kinda different things. It pretty much depends on what you need. One argument towards using Photoshop over Illustrator could be that very likely at some point you need photo editing capabilities, which Illustrator doesn't have. It's not all black and white... On the surface level, the answer here is: "Yes you can use PS for print design". Should you... or if it's actually the better application for you... That I can't say.

Comment: Thanks, @BillyKerr and I know the difference between raster and vector. All I want to know is can we use PS for flyers, magazine ads.

Comment: @AmitSaxena - yes of course you can. I am puzzled as to why you would even think you couldn't do that with Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks @Joonas for the answer. My only reason of using photoshop for print related design is because of its image editing capabilities. But some experts told me to use only ps for print designs. Anyways thanks for help.

Comment: I think anyone who has used Illustrator or Indesign enough to be comfortable with them would say they prefer them for print stuff and use Photoshop for retouching and what not, but none of that _really_ matters. It all comes down to what you want to do and what you're comfortable with. Whatever gets the job done. — That said... I wouldn't recommend limiting yourself to Photoshop. I could probably survive without Indesign or Illustrator, but I wouldn't enjoy it. I start sweating just thinking about making a 100-page manual using Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

You can even use MS Paint for print related designs. So yes, you can use Photoshop for print related designs.

The point, in reality, the tool's choice translates to maximizing things. Quality, time, resources, user skills, available tools, etc.

If Photoshop is the tool you know and you actually know what you are doing especially in terms of file resolution+output resolution you are fine.

---

**"Can" is different than "should".**

PSD files with layers and groups is a working file, not an output one. It is easy to turn off something that should have been printed and to leave on something that you should not have.

---

But depending on the job, PhotoDoNotUseItForEverythingShop starts to be not the right tool, and in some cases, it is simply the wrong one. In general, any raster file based program is.

For example, on commercial printing you have several issues, the text will be screened, you lose the ability to use overprint, your changes to texts will be a pain to update.

On big size prints, your text will be pixelated, and you will be forced to work with a heck bigger file than using a vector based program, you will lack to scale properly, not only assets but the output itself.

Simple changes in specific objects will be potentially a pain too.

And for a multipage document... you simply will regret using it.

---

> But some experts told me to use only ps for print designs.

This has no sense. A real expert will use the tool they need. If they need PS, ok, but **will use a heck of other tools for print**. PDF files; JPG or TIF using a different viewer; will use the RIP installed on the system; Illustrator, Corel Draw, Indesign, Scribus, Quark Express, etc; any raster based program... even MS Word. I'm sure some people can even use a console based program (that one where you type the instructions) to print...

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop is indeed a tool that can be used to create complete print designs. Many people do.

However, it is not intended to be used that way. Much in the same way you can use a wrench to drive a nail into a wall, you can use Photoshop to create a graphic design layout.

Performing typographical layouts like brochures in Photoshop comes with significant drawbacks. Photoshop is not designed to be a body copy editor, and it does not manage pages like you would see in InDesign or Illustrator.

The role of Photoshop in the graphic arts is much better suited as an image editor and asset generator. Those assets are then assembled in a layout program like InDesign.

So yes, you CAN design for print using nothing but Photoshop. Just realize that there are far superior tools out there that can do the job better, faster, and easier.

Answer (score -1):

### Yes - You Can Print Your Designs With Photoshop

But it depends what type of print you are doing.

If you are doing photographic type work for print, then `Photoshop` is best. However, if you are doing things like logos, `Illustrator` is best.

Both programs are designed for making printable files, but one can be better than the other for developing your images in.

---

### Photoshop Print Settings

[image]