# Resizing text and Images

Tags: images, resize, microsoft-powerpoint

I am designing a logo in PowerPoint with some text and a picture on top. How do I make the text and Image resize properly?

Currently, the picture moves position when I change the size. All objects are grouped together. I've tried locking the aspect ratio which doesn't help.

Comment: Most vector editing programs let you resize shapes but don't resize text the same way; instead, they assume that if you've set the text to, say, 24 point, that's what you want. Your best bet in this situation might be to get the shapes in your logo sized and arranged to suit you, then add text and adjust its size to suit.

Comment: I think you should use adobe illustrator or coral draw software for the resizing text and logo.

Answer (score 2):

> I am designing a logo in PowerPoint

I stopped after reading the first sentence, **why** are you designing a **logo** in PowerPoint?

---

You should be using a **vector** editing software such as;

- [Illustrator](https://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) ($)
- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) (free and open-source).

At worst you can get away with using a good photo editor like;

- [Photoshop](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html) ($)
- [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) (free and open-source).

  ---

If you use one of the above mentioned **vector** editors, you could easily align the objects + a boatload of other awesome features.

---

[What are the differences between vector graphics and raster graphics?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/260/63979)

[Raster vs Vector](https://vector-conversions.com/vectorizing/raster_vs_vector.html)

Comment: PowerPoint is, primarily, vector based. So why not use it, particularly if you have it and to one degree or another, know it better than some other program you've never worked with?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I personally don't use PowerPoint. (CMIIW) I don't think it has the same kind of export options as Illustrator or Inkscape which are essential for logo design.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what formats are required for the logo. If CMYK is needed, then no question, PPT is a non-starter. For RGB workflows (e.g. graphics for the web) it's fine; exports to JPG, PNG and a few other lesser-used raster formats. It also does a good job with PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you see the following harmful:

[image]

The upper arrow and the text inside the arrow are a group. When the group is selected and dragged to a bigger size, you get the lower version.

It's in PP to make possible to make room for a longer text and that it does very well.  Unfortunately that fights with your intentions and I haven't found an option to switch text scaling ON.

You can convert objects to vector images. Select those objects which you want to keep together in scalings and do "save as image". Select image format = EMF. Insert the saved image to your presentation. EMF is vector image which can also contain bitmap shapes.

You can explode the EMF image back to editable parts by selecting it and doing "Edit Image".

This all is only first aid and surely something can be also lost when objects are coverted to EMFs. I haven't tried all possible combinations.

Your best movement for future actions is to get a serious vector drawing program for image designs. Inkscape as freeware is one easy to get and quite capable option, as suggested.  Illustrator is the high cost option but also brings a good set of tools for professional users. Affinity designer, Corel Draw and Magix Xara are also commercial tools for pro users, but their prices are much lower.