# What should be the right approach to master Adobe Illustrator for beginners?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I mean after learning all the functions of different tools how should I proceed to master designing? What sources should I go through to have a clear cut idea of logo designing or how I can explore different things that I can do through Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE**! Please take a look around [tour] and learn who and what this community is. Also look at [ask] and [answer] a question to understand how to properly frame a query and what to expect of replies and answers. If you can take the time to look at [help/behavior] whilst you're at it, you'll get a clear sense of our community's internal behavioural expectations into the bargain. As current written, this question is... rather broad. I'd suggest looking over some of our canonical questions too for resources. Can you perhaps refine your question to be more specific?

Comment: For example:
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers

Comment: Or another: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-graphics-and-raster-graphics

Comment: To be honest all you have to master is the line tool, the ellipse tool and rotate/scale ,translate and skew tool, pathfinder and haape builder. + how strokes fills and art brushes work.

Comment: Learning how the pen tool works take at least twenty years, so start there! (Sarcasm) (But also some truth)

Comment: @mayersdesign yes that is also why i try tell people to avoid it, since it often brings nothing except problems to the table. its not that i dont use it, i do but often to get that perfect thing you need to use other things to support the pen tool first.

Answer (score 3):

Learning all the letters on the alphabet, learning all the definitions on the dictionary, does not mean you can write a "master" novel.

To see the potential of a language, English lets say, you probably need to compare the before and after Shakespeare, to read poems, or better, listen from the lips of an artist in reading poetry, and if is someone you care, the better.

---

Clicking buttons and menus will not make a logo, an illustration, a "master" pice. Only a few people accomplish that...

Take Illustrator... and turn it off. Now start looking logos, vector-based illustrations, digital paintings...

Now take your computer... and turn it off.

Go to a classic art museum, see a painting, Rembrandt, Velazquez, Goya, Raphael, Leonardo.

Now... contemplate.

.

.

.

Studying "history", not only classical paintings but also the history of graphic design, let's say of poster design, American, Russian European, Art deco, Vanguardism, Aerography in the '80s... is not to illuminate your mind, is to see how people are solving communication problems, using tools available to them. Limited printing capabilities, pallets, techniques and technologies.

---

Back to the computer. Put objectives on what you do, make a cartoon-like drawing, then do something more elaborate.

See you in some years from now.

---

Sayed that...

I do not mean to say this example is a masterpiece, but I know I feel free to move around vector based programs (and raster for that matter)

A. Make the base shapes. This means observing and deconstructing what you want to do. Imagine them as if you are cutting pieces of paper.

B. Here are the same shapes with a base color. Flat design, logos etc can stop at this point.

[image]

Add gradients, but you can do it the wrong way (C) or the right way (D).

C is the result of just adding a gradient **assuming** you know how things work... and D is actually observing both, real case examples and your own project and results.

That would be a vector-based Illustration.

[image]

But you can add some other resources. A vector based program can handle raster images, that you can process somewhere else, mainly Ps or similar programs.

Here I added a bitmap "sperized" And probably this should not be glossy anymore.

[image]

When making a vector-based illustration those parts would be essential.

Define shapes, define gradients, transparencies and blending modes.

Comment: Yes i agree, but ist not exactly enough to study paintings and so on. you need to learn to decompose what you see otherwise ist no use to look at things.

Answer (score 3):

To get a "master level" understanding of *any* Adobe **application**, read and study the *[Adobe Classroom In a Book](http://www.adobepress.com/series/series.asp?ser=334674)* from Peachpit Press for the application you want to learn.

It's dry, boring, and not very intriguing, but it will cover absolutely **every** aspect of the application. These are the "manuals" which Adobe no longer provides.

*In no instance* will this help with *creation* and *ideation*. Those are completely separate things. Learning a tool (such as software), has never improved one's ability to create designs. Merely the ability to see one's creations to fruition.

If you wish to improve your design skills... well.. that takes practice and self study or formal education.

Related: [Tips and resources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers)

Answer (score 1):

If you already know well all drawing tools and effects in Illustrator, you obviously also can draw different things with them at least by copying existing works or by working tutorials (you easily find hundreds of them). The next thing is to try to present something by yourself.

Take a pen and paper. Return to graphic software after you have drawn on the paper something which is reconizable, contains some idea  which you believe also others see in your drawing and you see it's good enough to be redrawn with sharp solid lines, shapes, texts and colors. It can be a sketch of a thing which exists in front of you, but you do not have already made drawing of it to be copied. A little later it can be an attempt to claim something. Claim = try to show relations and properties, real or artificial or both.

Being able to present humans, animals and their moods is difficult, one can practice years before he can draw them as he likes. Only simplest cartoon-like line drawings are possible in months.

Of course it can be difficult to do it in full isolation. You can start by watching already done works, say advertisements, for example. Try to say the same in other way or try to say something else of the same subject.