# Which file format produces the highest image quality for slideshows?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, image-quality, file-format, image-format

I'm working on a project, where I have to create images on PhotoShop. We're going to place my images on a slideshow. So far, I'm making sure to save my custom images as vector images and setting my dimensions as 2400px x 1500 px and 100 dpt.

I want my completed images to be as clear as possible, but I'm not sure which file format will be the best option to save and display in MS PowerPoint. I assume jpg would be the best, since I'm not sure MS Powerpoint would display pdf files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing some fundamentals because you say you're saving as vector images but then saying dimensions for them... Vector Images don't have dimensions. JPGs are raster images.

Typically if your image is vector, for example drawn using the pen tool in Adobe Illustrator, than you can import that vector file directly to Powerpoint as I believe SVG or EPS.

If on the other hand your image contains any raster elements, say a photograph or photo composite, then the highest quality would be BMP or TIFF (uncompressed) but its largely irrelevant for your purposes and JPG will be fine. Be sure to also check the [Image Size and Quality settings inside of Powerpoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-off-picture-compression-81a6b603-0266-4451-b08e-fc1bf58da658).

Further reading: [What are the differences between vector graphics and raster graphics?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-graphics-and-raster-graphics)