# Convert png into svg and then use it in html between svg tag

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, svg, html

I have web portfolio with images for the websites I worked on. For responsiveness I think SVG would be a better choice so that it does not lose any quality when browser is resized. For that reason I try to convert png images into svg using photoshop. Now there are several ways to use svg in html. One to use in `img` tag. Second `object` and third `embed`.

I tried above but images still get distorted and thus does not serve the purpose I am looking for. If I use `svg` tag put `paths` generated by photoshop might work better and scale better without losing any quality of images. Now the problem is that when I convert that image into svg using photoshop it does not give me `svg` tag with `paths` into. When I open that svg in browser and check source, I see below:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1400 713" width="1400" height="713">
    <defs>
        <image width="1400" height="713" id="img1" href="data:image/png;base64,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...>"/>
    </defs>
    <style>
        tspan { white-space:pre }
    </style>
    <use id="Background" href="#img1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"/>
</svg>
```

I am aware that there are alternative approaches too which are `srcset` and picture tag however for these I have create several images for the same image to keep the quality while the browser is scale up and down.

SVG seems to be better fit by using only one image and it will scale up and down with no or less distortion and images will look sleek on the browser.

So the question is how can I create svg so it has paths and then use it in html for better responsiveness while images still look sleek?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. That isn't a vector SVG. All you have there is an raster image within an SVG.  You can't convert a raster image to SVG unless you auto-trace it using vector software, or redraw it manually. Use something like Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape (free). Not Photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly helpful: [What are the differences between vector graphics and raster graphics?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-graphics-and-raster-graphics)

---

SVG, much like EPS, is merely a file "**wrapper**". What is inside the wrapper can be a mix of actual formats - vector or raster or both. Simply having an SVG file **never** means you have a vector file. All the SVG suffix means is the data is in the SVG wrapper, nothing more.

While the general purpose of SVG, or scalable **vector** graphics, is the ability to use *vector* files for the web - SVGs are *never* required to contain vector data. Simply wrapping a **raster** image, such as a png, in SVG tags does *not* magically convert the raster image format into a vector image format. Much the same way wrapping a ham sandwich in aluminum foil doesn't magically turn it into a hamburger -- the "wrapper" doesn't change the contents (the data).

You ***must*** covert any raster content into vector content if you wish to have paths, shapes, fills, and strokes which are the basis of vector data.

Using Photoshop, that often means *redrawing* the content using the *vector* tools within Photoshop. There is **no such thing** as being able to simply save or export a *raster* image and get vector results after the save/export. The data **must** be constructed in vector form if you wish to have vector output.

Many vector applications, such as Illustrator or Inkscape, have tracing features to auto-trace raster images converting them to vector. However, tracing is often hit or miss. Sometimes it does a good job, other times it doesn't. It all depends upon the original raster content.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot convert PNG images into SVG** in any meaningful way.

You write: "I have web portfolio with images for the websites I worked on".

The only way you'll be able to use SVG images for your web portfolio is **if you can export the SVG files from the program you originally used** to work on the websites.