# Logos created in Adobe illustrator gets pixeleted at edges while zooming

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png

I'm new to adobe illustrator and what I knew is if you create logo in illustrator it won't get pixeleted upon zooming.

I have created the logo in illustrator and within the same project when I was zooming my logo it doesn't get pixeleted I was happy. Exported it as png 24 with transparent background(it's the best quality what is know).

When I was using the same logo in a video(drag and drop), and when I zoom it , it gets pixeleted at edges. Which should not supposed to be.

What I know is illustrator creates vector and not working with pixels, they don't gets pixeleted no Matter how much you enlarge it. Please help me to get the right knowledge regarding my doubts.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The problem you are having is because PNG is a raster format (made of pixels), not a vector format. You can't zoom in on raster formats without seeing pixels. If you want to be able to zoom in, then PNG is the wrong format to choose. Export in a vector format instead, such as SVG, or PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my fellow designer already mentioned. You exported as a PNG, try exporting it as SVG.
But as I can tell from your comments you're also trying to upload this logo in a video/animation. I think you're trying to tell us that you're not able to upload a SVG in this video/animation and that you NEED a PNG that is not pixelated.

The thing is, if you have a small size PNG and try to scale it to a bigger size it get's pixelated of course.
The other way around is another story. You can try to export your logo VERY big in whatever program you used to create this logo with, I suppose it's Illustrator.
Import it as PNG into your video project and try to scale it down.

Comment: Sbaliyev thanks for your valuable suggestions, by the way I am using the same method which u have mentioned because at that time I thought to export it as large as I can so that scaling down will not affect in getting pixelated it was my last option and u also told me to do the same way, now I'm confident that the way I'm using is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a PNG it's *not* vector.

Once you export to PNG you no longer reap the benefits of vector paths within Illustrator.

The PNG is a **raster** (pixel) image and zooming in on it *will* always make pixel edges more pronounced.

You might want to check here: [What are the differences between vector graphics and raster graphics?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-graphics-and-raster-graphics)

Answer (score 0):

You drew a vector image in AI. Then you exported it as PNG which is a bitmap image format. The PNG file does not stand zooming in or scaling bigger without losing the guality - as you saw. If the file must be PNG it must be exported with as high pixel dimensions as needed for the wanted size, say 300 pixels per inch.

Exports as SVG, EMF and PDF are vector images except if one spoils it by rasterizing it at first or with bad export settings. Can you use other than PNG - that depends on your application which is unknown for us.

Comment: user287001 okay I got it, now if I want to use that logo in a video or picture then in that case does it supports svg, emf, or pdf? Is there any other way to use that logo  in videos and pictures without pixel edges? And one more thing how to export high quality transparent background logo? Please help,( I have just installed illustrator today, lots of things needs to be learned)

Comment: A guess: your video probably is something traditional - I mean every frame is a bitmap image.  If I guessed right the sharpest version of the logo is shown when it fills the whole video image.  Anything - if you zoom in the video as it runs or when you check a fully rendered frame - will be pixelated. What's the pixel dimensions of your video frames? Export your logo with these pixel dimensions. Add it to the video in full size to one track end make a smaller version by scaling down as picture in picture effect.

Comment: @KReEd (continued) Then you have room to zoom in (=less size reduction) in the video. Advanced video editors allow also vector images on tracks. They are converted to bitmaps when the final rendered file is mixed down. Unfortunately I have only a couple elementary video editors, nothing like After Effects or more advanced.

Comment: @KReEd it depends some video format containers can preserve some vector content, and some video editors can use vector content and output the optimal output resolution.